# How can I get the raw text of an email with Samsung's Mail client for Lollipop?

Tags: email, stock-email-app

Does Android Mail support the ability to get the raw as-sent text of an email? Alternatively, is there a way to forward an email **as an attachment**?

I'd like to be able to report spam email to Spamcop.net, but I need all the headers and the raw source of the email, not just a copy of the rendered results. I'd rather not depend on the Gmail app, as I connect to other email accounts as well.